# how to figure out how many relays are there in your tor URL?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, relays, exit-relays

Previously, reportedly there used to be three relays when you used torbrowser to go to your actual destination .

Your browser - relay1 (some IP country A) - relay 2 (some IP, country B) - relay 3 (some IP country C) - final destination URL.

Now for one thing, it seems it will be reduced to being used a single relay, but more worryingly I have not been able to figure out to know what relays are being used in torbrowser.

Can somebody help ?

Comment: "it will be reduced to being used a single relay" - why do you think this is the case?

Comment: To clarify why I am asking why you think that will happen: because it's not true.

Answer (score 2):

First about your single relay concern, I'm guessing you're referring to Single Onion Services (shamelessly stolen from [cacahuatl](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/12737/cacahuatl)'s answer to [this post](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14442/how-can-facebooks-tor-onion-be-constantly-accessible-with-the-massive-bandwidth#14444) and loosely edited), which are applied

> where one may not deem it important to hide
>   the location of the server but just want to gain the benefits of an
>   onion service.

And, as it's further explained in the same answer:

> If configured, the server will connect directly to the clients offered rendezvous 
>   point without building a full circuit first. This helps reduce and latency in the
>   building of the circuit and potential overloading of a chosen guard.

Now, to wrap it up, let's check your Tor Browser Circuit. Clicking on Show Site Information left of the address bar will display something like this:

[image: Tor Browser Onion Circuit check example]

*(found at a [related Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TOR/comments/algw1x/circuit_for_onion_sites_vs_circuit_for_clearnet/))*

There you have it, hope I've helped even after such a long time.

Cheers!